# DefaultPreparedStatement not serializable when starting Tomcat

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I am using Cassandra 3.10, Datastax driver 3.1.4 and Apache Lucerne index builder and Spring 4.3.2 to build a webapp to run in Tomcat 7.0.57.
I prepare all of my PreparedStatements into a Spring Singleton StatementFactory like:

```
selectLikeShortnameStmt = cassandraDatasource.getSession().prepare(" select  id, parent_id, ultimate_parent_id, internal_ref, short_name, long_name, controlling_team, " +
                                                " country_incorp, country_operate, company_reg, relationship_manager, credit_rating, rating_source, pd, lgd, review_date, sector, defaulted, own_bank_entity " +
                                                " from counterparty where short_name like ?");
```

and

```
selectByReviewDateAndRmQuery        = " select  id, parent_id, ultimate_parent_id, internal_ref, short_name, long_name, controlling_team, " +
                                            " country_incorp, country_operate, company_reg, relationship_manager, credit_rating, rating_source, pd, lgd, review_date, sector, defaulted, own_bank_entity " +
                                            " from counterparty where filter_column = '{ " 
                                                         + " filter : {type:\"range\", field:\"review_date\", lower:\"01-01-2000\", upper: \"%s\" },"
                                                         + " query : {type:\"contains\", field:\"relationship_manager\", values:[ \"%s\" ]},"
                                                         + " refresh:true"
                                                         + " }'";
```

In the first example the simple BIND method can be used but for the second example, the bind method states that there are no bind variables defined so I use the String.format method however when I start Tomcat I get an error stating DefaultPreparedStatement is not serializable:

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultPreparedStatement
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
at java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1785)
at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1362)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1028)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
at java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1785)
at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1362)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1028)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
at java.util.LinkedHashMap.internalWriteEntries(LinkedHashMap.java:333)
at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1362)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1028)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:441)
at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap.writeObject(Collections.java:2691)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1028)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObject(StandardSession.java:1695)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObjectData(StandardSession.java:1101)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doUnload(StandardManager.java:430)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.unload(StandardManager.java:351)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stopInternal(StandardManager.java:516)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5683)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1591)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1580)
... 4 more
```

**Although the code does not use DefaultPreparedStatement at all.**

In the DAO objects these are examples:

```
PreparedStatement pStmt = statementFactory.getSelectLikeShortnameStmt();
    BoundStatement bStmt = pStmt.bind( "%" + name + "%" );
    ResultSet rs = cassandraDatasource.getSession().execute( bStmt );
```

and

```
String query = statementFactory.getSelectByReviewDateAndTeamQuery();

    query = String.format( query, upperDate, controllingTeamCode );

    ResultSet rs = cassandraDatasource.getSession().execute( query );
```

Comment: In an attempt to narrow the field I have reworked the code so all DAO objects use the PreparedStatement structure as in the first example rather than using  a query string as in the second example but it makes no difference. Looking at the javadoc, DefaultPreparedStatement is the only class that implements the PreparedStatement interface  but no mention of it being Serializable is made.

Answer (score 0):

As DefaultPreparedStatement is the only class implementing the interface PreparedStatement and it does NOT implement the Serializable interface there appears to be no option other than to disable session persistance in Tomcat, this can be achieved by editing the context.xml in the tomcat conf directory